# Git: using branches for derived products

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, git-rebase

I was googling around on this and I couldn't find a similar situation, so here is my situation:

I have a demo application (Android app). Then a customer would like that application, the base will be the same, but some little changes need to be done (change name, icon, colors, etc).
In future, maybe specific customer changes will need to be applied.

Then I have another customer, same thing happens.

So I do:

```
git checkout -b customer_1
git checkout -b customer_2
```

do the changes...
Then I'm going to do some bugsolving in the demo app, or maybe add features there. These need to be integrated in the customer's version.

At the moment, I merge these in there, as I have a lack of ideas on how to do this otherwise.

I was Googling around and found something about `rebase`, but I still do not complete understand when to use that vs `merge`.

I have this situation since today and want to have a correct way of working from the start. I did 1 merge at the moment, but it doesn't feel right...

Git gurus, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: There's a reasonable write-up of merge vs rebase [here](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/10/git-team-workflows-merge-or-rebase/).  In general, you won't want to do this with branches because it will get pretty messy.  I would look into conditional compilation.

Comment: it looks like they only show feature branches which will live for a short time. My branches will live forever. Conditional compilation is not what I want. My code will get cluttered and I will need to have a different package name for each. They are really separate product with a communal base implementation

Comment: And with long lived branches, code for customer_1 and customer_2 will eventually drift apart enough that merging will become a huge headache.  I understand what you're trying to do and I don't think leaving that code on different branches will give you the result you're hoping for.

Comment: But I do not want conditional things in one project, to generate x different apps from it. That does not feel like a maintainable thing either. But I do not find any examples of other people facing the same problem

Comment: You might also want to take a look at the programmers.SE, specifically [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/134754/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-branches-to-maintain-different-editions-of-the-same) question.  Sounds like what you're asking about.

Comment: Thanks, I already found that link too, but it did not give me an answer. I am building an Android app, where the other products/apps can have a different UI for some screens, extra / less screens, different behavior on some parts. I cannot do this with config files and plugins/scripts. Also stuff from one customer may NEVER appear in the other

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to have a look at this tutorial about git, i'm pretty sure that it will help you a lot to find an answer to your solution:

[Learn Git Branching](http://pcottle.github.io/learnGitBranching)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at it! I hope it will answer my question of having a base implementation with derived, independent products

Comment: By following this tutorial, you'll get a good overview of the tools available to manage your project. The advantage of this interactive tutorial is that it stay focused on the git features.

Comment: I am going to use it to practice git during my working day. Thanks a lot. Awesome tutorial, somebody really did an effort here! I hope it will give me inspiration for a solution indeed